# Can't locate RPC/XML.pm Perl and RPC XML

Tags: perl, xml-rpc

I'm getting this error message when trying to to use the RPC XML with Perl.

> Software error:
>
> Can't locate RPC/XML.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at test.pl line 9.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 9.
> For help, please send mail to the webmaster ([no address given]), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

First I thought I didn't have XML-RPX installed. But when I look into a phpinfo()-file I find this:

> xmlrpc_error_number   0   0
>
> xmlrpc_errors Off Off

How come this error shows up? It looks to me as it is installed and PHP "finds it". But not Perl.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP having an xmlrpc config is no indication that the RPC::XML Perl module is installed, and the error message strongly suggests that it isn't (If it is, then it is outside the Perl library paths).

You need to [install](http://www.cpan.org/misc/cpan-faq.html#How_install_Perl_modules) the RPC::XML module.